# Javascript: Getting values from XML file

Tags: javascript, xml

This is my **exact** xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<blah_de_blah>          
    <unblocker_details  table_color="#F2F0FF" type="zip" alt_link="http://g.org/288"
 link_for_deletion="3-QQ5DJoa-AWFT7a9" comment="zippy"  />


    <unblocker_details  table_color="#FFFFFF" type="Webpage" alt_link="http://www.gg.com"
 link_for_deletion="4-rOX2brr-2qQeGY3" comment="test"  />

</blah_de_blah>
```

I have successfully gotten it via an ajax request, then did this:

```
var xmlDoc=null;
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
```

and now I need to get each of those values from `unblocker_details` into a variable:

for example:
the_table_color=table_color;
the_type =type;
etc

Please also check if I declared the xml properly as I am very new to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("unblocker_details");  

for(i=0; i< nodes.length; i++) {
   the_table_color = nodes[i].getAttribute("table_color");
   // get other attributes the same way
}
```

Comment: Hours and hours of frustration to finally get it to work... its been one of "those" days. Wish I could upvote this 100 times!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp